# MBAlertView Cannot call function inside " block:^{} "

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to use MBAlertView from cocoacontrol to make a confirmation box to ask user if they really want to delete some item.  Here is my code :

```
MBAlertView *alert = [MBAlertView alertWithBody:@"Are you sure you want to delete this note? You cannot undo this." cancelTitle:@"Cancel" cancelBlock:nil];
    [alert addButtonWithText:@"Delete" type:MBAlertViewItemTypeDefault block:^{

        //Code to delete the item
        [TheDatabaseManager deleteBabyActivityWithID:currentActivity.babyActivitiesID];
        [delegate refresh:currentActivity];
    }];

    [alert addToDisplayQueue];
```

And when user tap delete button it always crashes.
I get this error Message `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x0)"`
But it's OK if I just put another MBAlertView function inside the block (i.e : show another alert after user press delete)

Here is my .h file header :

```
#import "MBAlertView.h"
@interface ActivitiesPlayTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UIApplicationDelegate>{

}
```

I use this in table view cell, is that a problem?

Can anyone help me to solve this? 
I already looking for the answer trough the web but it seems that I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this alternative: https://github.com/stavash/UIBAlertView

Comment: Looks to me like your block tried to do its job and retain something.  Unfortunately, that something was in the process of being deallocated.

Comment: @Stavash : I'm downloading now. Thx for your suggestion

Comment: @CodaFi : What does it mean? It also crashes even when I just try to call some function like [self someFunction]

Comment: @TeguhHidayatullah keep in mind that it wraps the standard UIAlertView so you won't be able to get any special graphics from it. It's a UIAlertView with block callbacks